# Django automatically inheriting "abstract = true" from an abstract meta class

Tags: django, inheritance, abstract-class

I am using the following code.

```
class CommonFunctions(object):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/{0}/list/".format(self.__class__.__name__).lower()

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in   (self.__class__)._meta.fields]

    class Meta:
          abstract = True
```

The class is

```
class Book(models.Model, CommonFunctions):
        book_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        book_area = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Now if I use this I get an error,

> `ForeignKey` cannot define a relation with abstract class

But if I use

```
 class Meta:
      abstract = False
```

in the `Book` class then it works.

Why is it inheriting `true` if their [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/) says it should inherit `false`?

> Django does make one adjustment to the Meta class of an abstract base class: before installing the Meta attribute, it sets `abstract=False`. This means that children of abstract base classes don't automatically become abstract classes themselves.

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing that with us today, bidu. What's your question?

Comment: :) , My question is that their documentaion says that by defualt it will inherit False not true

Comment: @bidi - Perhaps you should post that as a Django bug report instead?

Comment: @Bo I am very new to Django and i don't think so that i can find bug in django so i was thinking i must be wrong somewhere

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `CommonFunctions` should be based on `models.Model`, not `object`. This way, you will get the behavior stated in the Django documentation.

```
class CommonFunctions(models.Model):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/{0}/list/".format(self.__class__.__name__).lower()

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in   (self.__class__)._meta.fields]

    class Meta:
          abstract = True
```

And then your `Book` class should be based only on `CommonFunctions`.

```
class Book(CommonFunctions):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    book_area = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: wow , thank you very very much , I was waiting for person like you to answer